# Sockets (Websockets), ports and protocols

Tags: sockets, websocket, connection, port

I wanted to know what is the relation between the sockets, ports and connection. How do they all fit together? 
It is seamlessly clear that sockets need some ports to let applications communicate together, but does websockets need ports too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is a protocol. It works over TCP connection, so it uses TCP sockets. A TCP socket is identified by host address and port number. So yes, WebSocket definitely needs port at the underlying layer.

As for the socket/connection relationship: a socket is an endpoint of a connection.